ArcGIS GeoEvent Server Configuration for a time dependent project
I am trying to make a service, which is needed to give me an alert if a vehicle runs for 20 minutes with a speed more than 75kmph. I have created two incident detector processor, for the first one is detecting speed higher than 75 kmph and second one taking the first one as a input and checking if the event is occuring for 30 minutes by putting the opening condition as duration>30. But it is not working. Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?
